# Custom UIFont rendering causes app to crash iOS 6

Tags: uikit, ios6, uifont

I test an app that uses a custom UIFont. This font is used in a UILabel that is zoomable -- it has a CATiledLayer layer.

This is the code for the UILabel class:

```
#import "ZoomableLabel.h"

@implementation ZoomableLabel

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

//- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
//    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
//    if (self) {
//        // Initialization code
//        [self setupView];
//    }
//    return self;
//}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupView];
}

- (void)setupView {
    CATiledLayer *layerForView = (CATiledLayer *)self.layer;
    layerForView.levelsOfDetailBias = 3;
    layerForView.levelsOfDetail = 1;
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)value {
    self.layer.contents = nil;
    [super setText:value];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)value {
    self.layer.contents = nil;
    [super setTextColor:value];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

When I run the app on a device or the simulator for the first time (that is the app is installed for the first time on the device or the simulator) I get a crash. Then this crash never happens again! UPDATE: The crash happens VERY randomly (especially when demoing the app...) but not only the first time. This is all the info I managed to get from XCode:

```
Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 3 Crashed: 0   WebCore                           0x333adbfa WTF::HashTable<WebCore::FontData const*, std::__1::pair<WebCore::FontData const*, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*>, WTF::PairFirstExtractor<std::__1::pair<WebCore::FontData const*, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*> >, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::FontData const*>, WTF::HashMapValueTraits<WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::FontData const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*> >, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::FontData const*> >::rehash(int) + 42
1   WebCore                         0x333adcd4 WTF::HashTableAddResult<WTF::HashTableIterator<WebCore::FontData const*, std::__1::pair<WebCore::FontData const*, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*>, WTF::PairFirstExtractor<std::__1::pair<WebCore::FontData const*, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*> >, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::FontData const*>, WTF::HashMapValueTraits<WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::FontData const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*> >, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::FontData const*> > > WTF::HashTable<WebCore::FontData const*, std::__1::pair<WebCore::FontData const*, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*>, WTF::PairFirstExtractor<std::__1::pair<WebCore::FontData const*, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*> >, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::FontData const*>, WTF::HashMapValueTraits<WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::FontData const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*> >, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::FontData const*> >::add<WTF::HashMapTranslator<WTF::HashMapValueTraits<WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::FontData const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*> >, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::FontData const*> >, WebCore::FontData const*, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode*>(WebCore::FontData const* const&, WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode* const&) + 56
2   WebCore                         0x333a5cac WebCore::GlyphPageTreeNode::getChild(WebCore::FontData const*, unsigned int) + 264
3   WebCore                         0x333a55d8 WebCore::Font::glyphDataAndPageForCharacter(int, bool, WebCore::FontDataVariant) const + 528
4   WebCore                         0x333a53b6 WebCore::Font::glyphDataForCharacter(int, bool, WebCore::FontDataVariant) const + 18
5   WebCore                         0x333a4b36 WebCore::WidthIterator::advance(int, WebCore::GlyphBuffer*) + 398
6   WebCore                         0x333a4794 WebCore::Font::floatWidthForSimpleText(WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::GlyphBuffer*, WTF::HashSet<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*> >*, WebCore::GlyphOverflow*) const + 60
7   WebCore                         0x333a4546 WebCore::Font::width(WebCore::TextRun const&, WTF::HashSet<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*> >*, WebCore::GlyphOverflow*) const + 250
8   WebCore                         0x333a60e0 WebCore::truncateString(WTF::String const&, float, WebCore::Font const&, unsigned int (*)(WTF::String const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned short*, bool), bool, float*, bool, float, bool) + 296
9   WebCore                         0x333a5fac WebCore::StringTruncator::rightTruncate(WTF::String const&, float, WebCore::Font const&, WebCore::StringTruncator::EnableRoundingHacksOrNot, float&, bool, float) + 60
10  WebKit                          0x375fc718 applyEllipsisStyle(WTF::String const&, WebEllipsisStyle, float, WebCore::Font const&, WebCore::StringTruncator::EnableRoundingHacksOrNot, float*, bool, float, bool) + 464
11  WebKit                          0x375ff3a8 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:drawUnderline:] + 5036
12  WebKit                          0x375fdfe8 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:] + 112
13  WebKit                          0x375fdf64 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:] + 108
14  WebKit                          0x375fdee4 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:] + 108
15  WebKit                          0x375fde64 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_sizeInRect:withFont:ellipsis:lineSpacing:] + 80
16  UIKit                           0x353698c2 -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:lineSpacing:] + 122
17  UIKit                           0x3535daa6 -[UILabel _legacy_drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 594
18  UIKit                           0x35321c5a -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 162
19  UIKit                           0x35320a26 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 446
20  UIKit                           0x35320860 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 68
21  UIKit                           0x3531fd20 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 360
22  QuartzCore                      0x37b84bb8 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 108
23  QuartzCore                      0x37c62624 tiled_layer_render(_CAImageProvider*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 1416
24  QuartzCore                      0x37bd755c CAImageProviderThread(unsigned int*, bool) + 508
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x37b5e95c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 248
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x37b5eabc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x38862a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
28  libsystem_c.dylib               0x388628a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Does anybody has any idea on this? I think this crash does not happen on an iOS 5 device...

Comment: Does anybody else met this situation? What shall I do? Report a bug to Apple? What?

Comment: I think I am seeing this same bug.  I haven't had a chance to thoroughly investigate it.  I was hoping someone else had already found the workaround.

Comment: I only get this crash on the Simulator.  So far.

Comment: I am getting the same crash, very frustrating. Removing the CALayer stops the crash but leaves me with blurry text. Any news on resolution?

Comment: @DanielNordh I just posted the answer to the problem. You should not have any issues with this code.

Comment: @Summon Amazing, thanks for setting me on the right track to fixing my only crashing bug! I have adjusted it to use Core Text instead as Core Graphics did not play nicely with other languages and odd font symbols. Have added an answer below for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on Summon's answer which uses Core Text to address issues with languages other than English (although I have only tested Swedish) and odd font symbols. Note that it uses initWithCoder as I'm using StoryBoard. It also shows how to center the text in the label horizontally (had less luck with vertical where I simply had to test my way to the right placement).

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface DNLabel : UILabel 

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "DNLabel.h"
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

@implementation DNLabel

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setupView];
    }
return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib 
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupView];
}

- (void)setupView {
CATiledLayer *layerForView = (CATiledLayer *)self.layer;
layerForView.levelsOfDetailBias = 10;
layerForView.levelsOfDetail = 10;
}

// LEAVE IT EMPTY
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
// UIView uses the existence of -drawRect: to determine if should allow its CALayer
// to be invalidated, which would then lead to the layer creating a backing store and
// -drawLayer:inContext: being called.
// By implementing an empty -drawRect: method, we allow UIKit to continue to implement
// this logic, while doing our real drawing work inside of -drawLayer:inContext:
}

// These calls inside this method are thread SAFE
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Core Text version
    CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)self.font.fontName,
                                            self.font.pointSize,
                                            NULL);
    // set color
    CGColorRef color = [[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75f] CGColor];

    // pack it into attributes dictionary
    NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    (id)CFBridgingRelease(ctFont), (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                    color, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    nil, (id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName, nil];

    // make the attributed string
    NSAttributedString *stringToDraw = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text
                                                                   attributes:attributesDict];
    // flip the coordinate system
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // check size of text and set position centered horizontally
    CGSize size = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font];
    CGContextSetTextPosition(context, self.bounds.size.width/2 - size.width/2, 1);

    // draw
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(
                                                    (CFAttributedStringRef)CFBridgingRetain(stringToDraw));
    CTLineDraw(line, context);
}

@end
```

Comment: nicely done. The code you provide is for NSAttributedString, which is a nice addition to my solution. I think the provided solution works with any font and language. In my project I use the provided code with a custom font. Mark the question as answered, if you believe so.

Comment: I am also using a custom font but had crashes with your answer when the label had swedish letters and it also didn't show some symbols /& etc. I don't think I can mark the question as answered as I didn't post it but glad I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

These are the .h and .m classes of a zoomable label based on CATiledLayer that never crashes:

Header:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ZoomableLabel : UILabel {
    CGPoint textDrawPoint;
    CGPoint shadowDrawPoint;
}

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ZoomableLabel.h"

@implementation ZoomableLabel

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupView];
}

- (void)setupView {
    CATiledLayer *layerForView = (CATiledLayer *)self.layer;
    layerForView.levelsOfDetailBias = 3;
    layerForView.levelsOfDetail = 1;
    textDrawPoint = CGPointMake(11, -22);
    shadowDrawPoint = CGPointMake(10, -23);
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        textDrawPoint = CGPointMake(11, -42);
        shadowDrawPoint = CGPointMake(8, -46);
    }
}

// DO NOT USER THESE METHODS ANYMORE
//-(void)setText:(NSString *)value {
////    self.layer.contents = nil;
//    [super setText:value];
//    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
//}
//
//-(void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)value {
////    self.layer.contents = nil;
//    [super setTextColor:value];
//    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
//}

// LEAVE IT EMPTY
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    // UIView uses the existence of -drawRect: to determine if should allow its CALayer
    // to be invalidated, which would then lead to the layer creating a backing store and
    // -drawLayer:inContext: being called.
    // By implementing an empty -drawRect: method, we allow UIKit to continue to implement
    // this logic, while doing our real drawing work inside of -drawLayer:inContext:
}

// These calls inside this method are thread SAFE
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Do all your drawing here. Do not use UIGraphics to do any drawing, use Core Graphics instead.
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    CGContextSelectFont(context, [self.font.fontName UTF8String], self.font.pointSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
//    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75f] CGColor]);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, shadowDrawPoint.x, shadowDrawPoint.y, [self.text UTF8String], self.text.length);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [self.textColor CGColor]);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, textDrawPoint.x, textDrawPoint.y, [self.text UTF8String], self.text.length);
}

@end
```